# Как правильно менять значение в БД через n времени?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
                к примеру есть
                таблица
            //Здесь нужно увеличить число "number" на percent от суммы 
            "number" (100/100)* 1,8 = 1,8+100 = 101,8 через 3 дня 
        так как истекает он через 3 дня 2023-02-09 16:57:38 для первой записи 
    и так для каждой
                //Counts
                id   number   percent  created_at         expires_at
                1    100        1.8    023-02-06 16:57:38 2023-02-09 16:57:38
                2    350        8.2    023-02-06 16:57:38 2023-02-13 16:57:38
                3    500        8.2    023-02-06 16:57:38 
                      
                
                
                //в другом случае
            //Counts
                id   number   percent  created_at         expires_at
                3    500        8.2    023-02-06 16:57:38 
                
             Если expires_at пусто, то "number" увеличивать просто на percent
 каждый день пока number не будет равно 1000 
т.е в 2 раза
```

Comment: каждый час это значит по расписанию. Расписание это значит либо крон и аналоги  в ОС, либо эвенты в mysql или аналоги в других СУБД, что вы используете

Comment: можете посмотреть я более подробно описал это то что вы имели ввиду?

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте
Либо cron
`* */1 * * * root /bin/sh /etc/blabla.sh` это расписание на каждый час
Либо демона

```
while(true) {
   тут ваш код по обновлению таблиц в бд...
   sleep(60*60);
}
```

Либо ивенты https://habr.com/ru/post/123391/